# Binning based on 1st column, multiple if else statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make binning on my second column with,

```
if(A1>1 and A1<4, slot1, if(A1>4 and A1<8, slot2, ...........so on)
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

[image: Checkout this image for clear idea]

Comment: Your screenshot does not match your description, and your description leaves the value of `4` undefined.  Edit your question to clarify what you want and show what you have tried and where you have run into problems. It might help if you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in ascending order, you can use `VLOOKUP` with approximate match.

First, you should add two helper columns (i put it in D:E), where you define the ranges:

[image: helper columns' data]

Then, you can use this formula:

`=VLOOKUP($A1,$D:$E,2,TRUE)`

which will produce this output:

[image: resulting data]

Answer (score 2):

One method:

```
="slot " & ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0)
```

[image]

Change `ROW()` to `ROW(A1)` in case your list doesn't start in row 1.

Comment: Nice. I'd rather use A1 instead of ROW() to make it work anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for help. what if I want to use variable slots. not of equal size?

Comment: @ASSerrano well then you'd have to explain your logic, in order to translate into a formula.

Comment: I am analysing data of a music channel, 1-24 are hour slots of day and I want to segregate these slots because audience is different for say morning , afternoon, evening. so if I want to set slot from 7-11 morning , 11-5 ~afternoon ......

Comment: I will accept this answer for now but please try to solve my 2nd question if possible.

Comment: @ASSerrano - I would propose asking it as a new question, including that relevant detail from your previous comment. That's the best chance of getting an appropriate answer. Please include relevant sample data, as well as the expected result, thanks! Feel free to ping me here with the new question link too.

Comment: @ASSerrano have a look at my answer, i think it satisfies your requirement. in the future, don't be so hasty to accept an answer, as once an answer is accepted, you're unlikely to get input from other users. welcome to SO. :)